# Difference between innerText, innerHTML and value?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, innertext

What is the difference between `innerHTML`, `innerText` and `value` in JavaScript?

Comment: @tymeJV Honestly, the distinction with `innerText`, a non-standard implementation of textContext by MSIE, is non-trivial.

Comment: In addition to innerText not working in Firefox: textContent seems to work in all major browsers, so just use textContent instead of innerText.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: The 3 comments above are no longer valid. `innerText` has been added to the standards and supported by all major browsers. `textContent` is now supported by IE>=9 and can be used instead of `innerText` in most cases (bonus, it is much faster), but there are differences between the two, so in some cases you cannot swap them.

Comment: Update 2019: `innerText` is well supported in all browsers. Firefox started supporting it from version 45. https://caniuse.com/#search=innertext

Comment: I am surprised that security is not addressed here. `innerHTML`  is a known vulnerability for XSS attacks. That said, `innerText` is not 100% secure either.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707031/does-innertext-prevent-xss
https://blog.cloudboost.io/why-textcontent-is-better-than-innerhtml-and-innertext-9f8073eb9061

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Unlike `innerText`, though, `innerHTML` lets you work with HTML rich text and doesn't automatically encode and decode text. In other words, `innerText` retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text, whereas `innerHTML` retrieves and sets the content in HTML format.

Comment: Very important to paste here in the accepted answer @jor's comment below in another answer:

"Just for clearity: This only applies when SETTING a value. When you're GETTING the value HTML tags are simply stripped and you get the plain text."

Comment: Importantly, and perhaps unintuitively, setting an element's `innerText` with a multiline text value (containing CRLFs) will encode those CRLFs to `<BR>`'s.

Answer (score 310):

The examples below refer to the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="test">
   Warning: This element contains <code>code</code> and <strong>strong language</strong>.
</div>
```

The node will be referenced by the following JavaScript:

```
var x = document.getElementById('test');
```

#### `element.innerHTML`

[Sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

```
x.innerHTML
// => "
// =>   Warning: This element contains <code>code</code> and <strong>strong language</strong>.
// => "
```

This is part of the W3C's [DOM Parsing and Serialization Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML). Note it's a property of `Element` objects.

#### `node.innerText`

[Sets or gets the text between the start and end tags of the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
x.innerText
// => "Warning: This element contains code and strong language."
```

- `innerText` was introduced by Microsoft and was for a while unsupported by Firefox. In August of 2016, `innerText` was [adopted by the WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) and was added to Firefox in v45.
- `innerText` gives you a style-aware, representation of the text that tries to match what's rendered in by the browser this means:

  - `innerText` applies `text-transform` and `white-space` rules
  - `innerText` trims white space between lines and adds line breaks between items
  - `innerText` will not return text for invisible items
- `innerText` will return `textContent` for elements that are never rendered like `<style />` and `
- Property of `Node` elements

#### `node.textContent`

[Gets or sets the text content of a node and its descendants.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

```
x.textContent
// => "
// =>   Warning: This element contains code and strong language.
// => "
```

*While this is a [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent), it is not supported by IE < 9.*

- Is not aware of styling and will therefore return content hidden by CSS
- Does not trigger a reflow (therefore more performant)
- Property of `Node` elements

#### `node.value`

This one depends on the element that you've targeted. For the above example, `x` returns an [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) object, which does not have a `value` property defined.

```
x.value // => null
```

Input tags (`<input />`), for example, do [define a `value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), which refers to the "current value in the control".

```
<input id="example-input" type="text" value="default" />
<script>
  document.getElementById('example-input').value //=> "default"
  // User changes input to "something"
  document.getElementById('example-input').value //=> "something"
</script>
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

> Note: for certain input types the returned value might not match the
>   value the user has entered. For example, if the user enters a
>   non-numeric value into an `<input type="number">`, the returned value
>   might be an empty string instead.

### Sample Script

Here's an example which shows the output for the HTML presented above:

```js
var properties = ['innerHTML', 'innerText', 'textContent', 'value'];

// Writes to textarea#output and console
function log(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  var currValue = document.getElementById('output').value;
  document.getElementById('output').value = (currValue ? currValue + '\n' : '') + obj; 
}

// Logs property as [propName]value[/propertyName]
function logProperty(obj, property) {
  var value = obj[property];
  log('[' + property + ']'  +  value + '[/' + property + ']');
}

// Main
log('=============== ' + properties.join(' ') + ' ===============');
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
  logProperty(document.getElementById('test'), properties[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Warning: This element contains <code>code</code> and <strong>strong language</strong>.
</div>
<textarea id="output" rows="12" cols="80" style="font-family: monospace;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Even the most recent versions of Firefox do not support `innerText`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/innerhtml.html

Comment: It would be helpful to have each of the four properties (innerHTML, innerText, textContent, value) divided into two subheadings: "get" behavior and "set" behavior.

Comment: I find getting innerText useful for GUI automation, so you can assert the text the user sees.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText `Firefox >=45` is supported.

Comment: If I understand the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) correctly, `innerText` is now part of the Standard and should be supported by Firefox from version 45 on; maybe reason for an update to this great answer @faraz

Comment: It also converts `&lt;` to `<`, `&gt;` to `>`, etc.

Answer (score 29):

`InnerText` property html-encodes the content, turning `<p>` to `&lt;p&gt;`, etc. If you want to insert HTML tags you need to use `InnerHTML`.

Comment: Just for clearity: This only applies when SETTING a value. When you're GETTING the value HTML tags are simply stripped and you get the plain text.

Answer (score 17):

In simple words:

1. `innerText` will show the value as is and ignores any `HTML` formatting which may 
   be included.
2. `innerHTML` will show the value and apply any `HTML` formatting.

Answer (score 16):

**Both `innerText` and `innerHTML` **return internal part** of an HTML element.**

The **only difference between `innerText` and `innerHTML`** is that: `innerText` return HTML element (entire code) as a string and display HTML element on the screen (as HTML code), while `innerHTML` return only text content of the HTML element.

Look at the example below to understand better. Run the code below.

```js
const ourstring = 'My name is <b class="name">Satish chandra Gupta</b>.';
document.getElementById('innertext').innerText = ourstring;
document.getElementById('innerhtml').innerHTML = ourstring;
```

```css
.name {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Inner text below. It inject string as it is into the element.</b></p>
<p id="innertext"></p>
<br>
<p><b>Inner html below. It renders the string into the element and treat as part of html document.</b></p>
<p id="innerhtml"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes[1].innerText;
alert('the value is:' + values);
```

To further refine it and retrieve the value Alec for example, use another .childNodes[1]

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerText;
alert('the value is:' + values);
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of `MutationObservers`, setting `innerHTML` generates a `childList` mutation due to the browsers removing the node and then adding a new node with the value of `innerHTML`.

If you set `innerText`, a `characterData` mutation is generated.

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` property sets or returns the text content as plain text of the specified node, and all its descendants, whereas the `innerHTML` property gets and sets the plain text or HTML contents in the elements. Unlike `innerText`, `innerHTML` lets you work with HTML rich text and doesn’t automatically encode and decode text.

Answer (score 1):

`InnerText` will only return the text value of the page with each element on a newline in plain text, while `innerHTML` will return the HTML content of everything inside the `body` tag, and `childNodes` will return a list of nodes, as the name suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The `innerText` property returns the **actual text** value of an html element while the `innerHTML` returns the `HTML content`. Example below:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('hello');
element.innerText = '<strong> hello world </strong>';
console.log('The innerText property will not parse the html tags as html tags but as normal text:\n' + element.innerText);

console.log('The innerHTML element property will encode the html tags found inside the text of the element:\n' + element.innerHTML);
element.innerHTML = '<strong> hello world </strong>';
console.log('The <strong> tag we put above has been parsed using the innerHTML property so the .innerText will not show them \n ' + element.innerText);
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="hello"> Hello world 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list, `innerText` will keep your `text-transform`, `innerHTML` wont.

Answer (score 1):

@rule:

`innerHTML`

- write: whatever String you write to the `ele.innerHTML`, `ele` (the code of the element in the html file) will be exactly same as it is written in the String.
- read : whatever you read from the `ele.innerHTML` to a String, the String will be exactly same as it is in `ele` (the html file).

- => `.innerHTML` will **not make any modification** for your read/write

`innerText`

- write: when you write a String to the `ele.innerText`, any `html reserved special character` in the String will be **encoded** into html format first, then stored into the `ele`.

  - eg: `<p>` in your String will become `&lt;p&gt;` in the `ele`
- read : when you read from the `ele.innerText` to a String,

  1. any `html reserved special character` in the `ele` will be **decoded** back into a readable text format,

     - eg: `&lt;p&gt;` in the `ele` will become back into `<p>` in your String
  2. any (valid) `html tag` in the `ele` will be **removed** -- so it becomes "plain text"

     - eg: `if <em>you</em> can` in the `ele` will become `if you can` in your String

     - about invalid `html tag`

       - if there is an invalid `html tag` originally in the `ele` (the html code), and you read from`.innerText`, how does the tag gets removed?

         -- this ("if there is an invalid `html tag` originally") should not (is not possible to) happen
       - but its possible that you write an invalid `html tag` by `.innerHTML` (in raw) into `ele` -- then, this may be auto fixed by the browser.

     - dont take (-interpret) this as step [1.] [2.] with an order
       -- no, take it as step [1.] [2.] are executed at the same time

       -- I mean, if the decoded characters in [1.] will form a new tag after the conversion, [2.] does not remove it

       (-- cuz [2.] considers what characters are in the `ele` during the conversion, not the characters they become into after the conversion)
  3. then stored into the String.

---

[jsfiddle: with explanation](https://jsfiddle.net/SelectNt/j4yfm8b5/)

- (^ this contains much more explanations in comments of the js file, + output in console.log

  below is a simplified view, with some output.

  (try out the code yourself, also there is no guarantee that my explanations are 100% correct.))

```html
<p id="mainContent">This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.</p>
<p id="htmlWrite"></p>
<p id="textWrite"></p>
```

```js
// > @basic (simple)
// read
var ele_mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
alert(ele_mainContent.innerHTML); // This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.        // >" + => `.innerHTML` will **not make any modification** for your read/write
alert(ele_mainContent.innerText); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.                         // >" 2. any (valid) `html tag` in the `ele` will be **removed** -- so it becomes "plain text"

// write
var str_WriteOutput = "Write <strong>this</strong> sentence to the output.";
var ele_htmlWrite = document.getElementById('htmlWrite');
var ele_textWrite = document.getElementById('textWrite');
ele_htmlWrite.innerHTML = str_WriteOutput;
ele_textWrite.innerText = str_WriteOutput;

alert(ele_htmlWrite.innerHTML); // Write <strong>this</strong> sentence to the output.               // >" + => `.innerHTML` will **not make any modification** for your read/write
alert(ele_htmlWrite.innerText); // Write this sentence to the output.                                // >" 2. any (valid) `html tag` in the `ele` will be **removed** -- so it becomes "plain text"                     
alert(ele_textWrite.innerHTML); // Write &lt;strong&gt;this&lt;/strong&gt; sentence to the output.   // >" any `html reserved special character` in the String will be **encoded** into html format first               
alert(ele_textWrite.innerText); // Write <strong>this</strong> sentence to the output.               // >" 1. any `html reserved special character` in the `ele` will be **decoded** back into a readable text format,  

// > @basic (more)
// write - with html encoded char
var str_WriteOutput_encodedChar = "What if you have &lt;strong&gt;encoded&lt;/strong&gt; char in <strong>the</strong> sentence?";
var ele_htmlWrite_encodedChar = document.getElementById('htmlWrite_encodedChar');
var ele_textWrite_encodedChar = document.getElementById('textWrite_encodedChar');
ele_htmlWrite_encodedChar.innerHTML = str_WriteOutput_encodedChar;
ele_textWrite_encodedChar.innerText = str_WriteOutput_encodedChar;

alert(ele_htmlWrite_encodedChar.innerHTML); // What if you have &lt;strong&gt;encoded&lt;/strong&gt; char in <strong>the</strong> sentence?
alert(ele_htmlWrite_encodedChar.innerText); // What if you have <strong>encoded</strong> char in the sentence?
alert(ele_textWrite_encodedChar.innerHTML); // What if you have &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;encoded&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt; char in &lt;strong&gt;the&lt;/strong&gt; sentence?
alert(ele_textWrite_encodedChar.innerText); // What if you have &lt;strong&gt;encoded&lt;/strong&gt; char in <strong>the</strong> sentence?


// > @note-advance: read then write 
var ele__htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite = document.getElementById('htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite');
var ele__htmlRead_Then_textWrite = document.getElementById('htmlRead_Then_textWrite');
var ele__textRead_Then_htmlWrite = document.getElementById('textRead_Then_htmlWrite');
var ele__textRead_Then_textWrite = document.getElementById('textRead_Then_textWrite');

ele__htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerHTML = ele_mainContent.innerHTML;
ele__htmlRead_Then_textWrite.innerText = ele_mainContent.innerHTML;
ele__textRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerHTML = ele_mainContent.innerText;
ele__textRead_Then_textWrite.innerText = ele_mainContent.innerText;

alert(ele__htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerHTML); // This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerText); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__htmlRead_Then_textWrite.innerHTML); // This is a &lt;strong&gt;sample&lt;/strong&gt; sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__htmlRead_Then_textWrite.innerText); // This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__textRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerHTML); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__textRead_Then_htmlWrite.innerText); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__textRead_Then_textWrite.innerHTML); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.
alert(ele__textRead_Then_textWrite.innerText); // This is a sample sentennce for Reading.


// the parsed html after js is executed
/*
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="mainContent">This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.</p>
<p id="htmlWrite">Write <strong>this</strong> sentence to the output.</p>
<p id="textWrite">Write &lt;strong&gt;this&lt;/strong&gt; sentence to the output.</p>
<!-- P2 -->
<p id="htmlWrite_encodedChar">What if you have &lt;strong&gt;encoded&lt;/strong&gt; char in <strong>the</strong> sentence?</p>
<p id="textWrite_encodedChar">What if you have &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;encoded&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt; char in &lt;strong&gt;the&lt;/strong&gt; sentence?</p>
<!-- P3 @note: -->
<p id="htmlRead_Then_htmlWrite">This is a <strong>sample</strong> sentennce for Reading.</p>
<p id="htmlRead_Then_textWrite">This is a &lt;strong&gt;sample&lt;/strong&gt; sentennce for Reading.</p>
<p id="textRead_Then_htmlWrite">This is a sample sentennce for Reading.</p>
<p id="textRead_Then_textWrite">This is a sample sentennce for Reading.</p>

</body></html>
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

innerhtml will apply html codes

innertext will put content as text so if you have html tags it will show as text only

Answer (score 0):

1)innerHtml

- sets all the html content inside the tag
- returns all the html content inside the tag
- includes styling + whitespaces

[image]
[image]

2)innerText

- sets all the content inside the tag (with tag wise line breaks)
- returns all html content inside the tag (with tag wise line breaks)
- ignores tags (shows only text)
- ignores styling + whitespaces
- if we have style:"visibility:hidden;" inside tag
  |_ innerText includes the styling -> hides content

[image]
[image]

3)textContent

- sets all the content inside the tag (no tag wise line breaks)
- returns all content inside the tag (no tag wise line breaks)
- includes whitespaces
- if we have style:"visibility:hidden;" inside tag
  |_ textContent ignores the styling -> shows content
- textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.
  [image]
  [image]