# Why does changing innerText value also changes innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, innerhtml, innertext

I have a asp.net code that creates a button as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="button1" title="Maximize" onclick="function1('span1')" class="button"><span id="span1" class="iconMaximizeLightText">Maximize</span></a>
```

now in the javascript file I am doing the following inside the function1 function:

```
document.getElementById("button1").innerText = "Minimize";
document.getElementById("button1").value = "Minimize";
document.getElementById("button1").className = "iconMinimizeLightText";
```

What I noticed was before the line : "document.getElementById("button1").innerText = "Minimize";" is executed the value in "document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML" is

```
document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "<span id=span1 class=iconMaximizeLightText>Maximize</span>"
```

but after that line is executed the value in "document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML" is

```
document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "Minimize"
```

Why is innerHTML value changing as I only changed the innerText value ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry this might be a stupid question but I have only started learning this language since a couple of weeks.

Comment: See [Difference between innerText and innerHTML in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Both `innerText` and `innerHTML` set the HTML of the element. The difference is that `innerText`—by the way, you might want to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead—will escape the string so that you can't embed HTML content in it.

So for example, if you did this:

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerText = '<span>Hello</span>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Then you'd actually see the string `"<span>Hello</span>"` on the screen, as opposed to `"Hello"` (inside a span).

There are some other subtleties to `innerText` as well, which are covered in the MDN article referenced above.