# Why does changing textContent value also changes HTML

Tags: javascript

I have the below code in a website and I need to change the "Getting Started" text

```html
<h4 data-v-318a1596="" class="h4">
  <div data-v-318a1596="">
    <i data-v-318a1596="" class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color: rgb(141, 153, 166); font-size: 18px; margin-right: 6px;"></i> 
    Getting Started
  </div>
</h4>
```

As I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999375/why-does-changing-innertext-value-also-changes-innerhtml) I tried to use `textContent` as below;

```
document.getElementsByClassName('h4')[0].childNodes[0].textContent='My text here'
```

The above code replaces the text but it also replaces the other HTML part specifically below;

```
<i data-v-318a1596="" class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color: rgb(141, 153, 166); font-size: 18px; margin-right: 6px;"></i>
```

So after running my code the source looks like below;

```
<h4 data-v-318a1596="" class="h4"><div data-v-318a1596="">My text here</div></h4>
```

Could you please help me to replace only the text part?

Comment: Per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): "Setting textContent on a node removes all of the node's children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value."

Comment: You need to wrap the Getting Started text in a seperate element such as `span` in order to use `textContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change textNodes but you have to navigate the DOM to get there

```js
const divToChange = document.querySelector(".h4 > div");
const textNode = divToChange.querySelector("i").nextSibling;
divToChange.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("Finish the job"),textNode)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<h4 data-v-318a1596="" class="h4">
  <div data-v-318a1596="">
    <i data-v-318a1596="" class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color: rgb(141, 153, 166); font-size: 18px; margin-right: 6px;"></i> 
    Getting Started
  </div>
</h4>
```

It is of course simpler to have a span

If you can change that, then you can change the invalid h4 too

```js
document.querySelector(".h4 > div > span").textContent = "Finish the job"
```

```css
.h4 span { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<div data-v-318a1596="" class="h4">
  <div data-v-318a1596="">
    <i data-v-318a1596="" class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color: rgb(141, 153, 166); font-size: 18px; margin-right: 6px;"></i> 
    <span>Getting Started</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't own the website so I have to navigate the code. Thanks a log again!