# How to find if an HTML element is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, is-empty, innertext

I want to find out if an element is empty or not. Probably this is one of the best examples to help people understand **difference between innerText and innerHTML** as well.

Here are the examples:

```
1. <div> <!-- Just a comment node is present inside a div --> </div>

2. <div> <span></span> </div>

3. <div> hi </div>

4. <div> hello <!-- world --> I know javascript </div>

5. <div>    </div>
```

**Example_Number |  innerHTML |  innerText | #childElements | isElementEmpty(Result)**

1............................|  Not Empty....| Empty........| 0.........................| YES

2............................| Not Empty....| Empty........| 1.........................| No

3............................| Not Empty....| Not Empty..| 0.........................| No

4............................| Not Empty....| Not Empty..| 0.........................| No

5............................| Empty..........| Empty.........| 0.........................| Yes

*In #5, trimmed value is considered.*

Clearly, **innerHTML does not contribute** to check whether an element is empty or not. Now, we need to check how innerText/textContent and numberOfChildElement contribute. So based on above findings, I have concluded

An element is empty when both of these conditions is met.

1. Trimmerd innerText/textContent is empty. (Satisfies #5)
2. Number of child elements is ZERO. (Satisfies #2)

So the code becomes

```
function isEmpty(element) {
  return (element.textContent.trim() && element.childElementCount == 0);
}
```

I just want to validate my approach and tell if I miss any use case here or a better solution would be really helpful.

Comment: Just to add some information, textContent is supported in all browsers while FF does not support innerText So I have used textContent in the code

Comment: here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript

Comment: FYI `.childElementCount`, `.textContent` and `.trim()` require IE9 or higher so this solution would only be for IE9+.

Comment: What is your criteria for empty?  No visible text?  Consumes no space?  Or no visible text and no child elements?  I could argue that none of your 5 examples are actually empty as all have child nodes with at least some content.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, an element is empty is there is no html element inside it and there is no visible text.  Moreover, yes IE9+ solution is what i wanted to support. Thanks for asking this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Doing it like this: `return (element.childElementCount === 0 && element.textContent.trim());` would be more efficient if there were lots of child objects with text because it would avoid evaluating `.textContent` in those cases which has to traverse the entire child tree.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah..That is a great optimization. I just want to ensure that I did not miss any use case.

Comment: @blunderboy - I'd suggest you edit your question to make it 100% clear what your question is.  You've already gotten one answer that isn't about what you say the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Innertext is just plain text.Whatever you put in the innertext will be shown as plain text.i.e.a text like `"<b>sdasdas</b>" will be shown as "<b>sdasdas</b>`"
InnerHTML is plain html code.WHatever you put in innerHTML will be treated as HTML code.i.e.a text like `"<b>sdasdas</b>" will be shown as "sdasdas" in bold letters`

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The question was "Difference between innerText and innerHTML (Used to find en element is empty or not)".So I think my comment is qualified to be an answer

Comment: See recent comment by the OP.  That isn't their question.

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar I apologize for causing some confusion about the tile. Isn't my question clear now from the title and table I have given ?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared example which is help you to understand difference between innerText and innerHTML and other related function

```
<HTML><BODY>
<div id="div1">
<H1><B>Hi<I> There</I></B></H1>
</div>
innerText: Works only in IE browser<br/>
innerHTML: work on all browser and return html content<br/>
textContent : Remove html tag from content<br/>
Jquery function to get text / HTML <br/>
.text()<br/>
.html()<br/>
<input id="innerText" type="button" value="innerText"/>
<input id="innerHTML" type="button" value="innerText"/>
<input id="textContent" type="button" value="textContent"/>
<input id="text" type="button" value=".text()"/>
<input id="html" type="button" value=".html()"/>
```

---

```
$( "#innerText" ).click(function() {

alert(document.getElementById("div1").innerText);
});

$( "#innerHTML" ).click(function() {
   alert(document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML);
});

$( "#textContent" ).click(function() {
   alert(document.getElementById("div1").textContent);
});

$( "#text" ).click(function() {
   alert( $("#div1").text());
});

$( "#html" ).click(function() {
   alert( $("#div1").html());
});
```