# How do I access the text within a web component?

Tags: polymer, web-component

Given the following example element.

```
<my-element>
   Hello world
</my-element>
```

What javascript variable would give me "Hello world"?

I've tried a bunch of things. I tried `this.innerText`, and `this.$.content` won't show unless the `<content>` tags are in the `<template>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, I'm not sure if it's cross-browser:

```
this.textContent
```

Here's how I got there

- [Polymer/docs/issues/256](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/256).
- [Difference between innerText and innerHTML in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)