# AutoHotKey JavaScript Link

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

I'm not familiar with JavaScript and web development, as my experience is in Java and C++ primarily, and I'm even new to that. I'm using AutoHotKey to automate data entry for the company I work for, and in order to get into the form that to fill out a new item, I have to click a link. I've had no problem when the links all had URLs for `href` values, but now I'm running into one that is a JavaScript link, and I don't know how to click it... here is the code for the link.

```
<a href="javascript:" 
tabindex="7"
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode._skip=true;$find('ctl00_MainContent_view1Extender').executeAction('ActionBar',0,null,0);return false;"
onfocus="$showHover(this,&quot;ctl00_MainContent_view1Extender$0$ActionGroup$0&quot;,&quot;ActionGroup&quot;,2)" 
title="New Reimbursement" 
onblur="$hideHover(this)">New Reimbursement</a>
```

And I'm not sure what to do with it, despite a days worth of Googling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to click it?

Comment: I've tried finding it by `wb.document.links[x].href` so that I could `wb.Navigate` to it

Comment: I also tried copying and pasting `javascript:(onClick text)`

Comment: Somehow you need to run the `onclick` event, the `href` does nothing. Can you trigger the click event by calling `.click()` on the DOM node?

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose I should have looked into that. The problem I'm having is that the element doesn't have an id... so I don't know how to reference it.

Comment: I'm thinking this: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85281-help-with-ahk-l-and-the-dom/

Comment: Just making a note for myself for tomorrow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript

Comment: I am not sure but maybe that can help you: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/84258-iwb2-learner-iwebbrowser2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More then one way get to an element without a ID or Name, but one of the easy ones are to loop over the elements on the page until you get to the one you need.

**Example Function:**

```
LoopElements(Elements, String, attribute="title")
{
try
Loop % Elements.Length ; check each element
    If instr((Elements[A_Index-1])[Attribute], String) ; if the Attribute text is what we need
        return Elements[A_Index-1] ; return Element
}
```

Most of the time the `.click()` method will work but with the newest versions of IE I have seen a need to use other methods like dispatchEvent to make a mouseevent object

**Usage example:**

```
site := "ahkscript.org"

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.visible := true
wb.navigate(site)

while wb.readyState!=4 || wb.document.readyState != "complete" || wb.busy
    continue

links := wb.document.getElementsByTagName("A")

linkElement := LoopElements(links, "GNU General Public License", "innertext")

if (linkElement)
{
    msgbox % "Element found it was #" linkElement.sourceindex "`n`nLets click it!"
    linkElement.click()
}
else
    msgbox % "no Element found"
return



LoopElements(Elements, String, attribute="title")
{
try
Loop % Elements.Length ; check each element
    If instr((Elements[A_Index-1])[Attribute], String) ; if the Attribute text is what we need
        return Elements[A_Index-1] ; return Element
}
```

You can also call the function the onclick event is doing but try this first then later you can try other ways as you get the need...

Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up with an "Access Denied" error when I ran my script, pointing to the line where I executed `.click()` I will run it with your method and see if it works. Thanks for the info. I will report back.

Comment: Baby Jesus, it works. Thanks for your help!!! I may be back here in the near future. I hope you will be around. }:)