# Make table TD bold if it does not contain dash

Tags: javascript

Here is the code but not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var emptyTar = document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerText;

if(emptyTar.indexOf('-') === -1)
{
  emptyTar.bold();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("td")` gives you the list of matched elements not just one element. You need to loop through the list to get it's `innerText`

Comment: Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript) before using `innerText`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns collection of elements, not single element. You have to make a loop over this collection.

```
var emptyTar = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < emptyTar.length; i++) {
    if (emptyTar[i].innerHTML.indexOf('-') === -1) {
        emptyTar[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ydwqLns/1/

Comment: Thanks. I also need to make sure, innerHTML is not number. below is not working

if (emptyTar[i].innerHTML != NaN && emptyTar[i].innerHTML.indexOf('-') === -1) {

Comment: @ImranJafri: `parseInt` in is your friend.

Comment: Too embarrassed to say I have not brushed up my JS in 2 years. :) can modify above code? :)

Comment: @ImranJafri: if I understood you, this should be okay: http://jsfiddle.net/8ydwqLns/2/

Answer (score 0):

You clould do

```
 var emptyTar = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
 for(i = 0;i < emptyTar.length; i++)
{
   if(emptyTar[i].innerText.indexOf('-') === -1)
   {
      emptyTar[i].innerHtml = emptyTar[i].innerText.bold();

    }
}
```