# How can I render the content of a contenteditable div as HTML inside another element?

Tags: javascript

In the example below, entering HTML into the `contenteditable` div should render as HTML inside `#html_view`, but instead of rendering as HTML it is rendering as text.

For example: when entering the following HTML, it should render "sometext" inside a red container but the string is transferred as is.

```
<p style="background-color:red;">sometext</p>
```

How can I render the content of a `contenteditable` div as HTML inside another element?

```js
function move_to_the_other_div(el){
 document.getElementById('html_view').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#html_view{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:50px;
}
#code_view{
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:50px;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="html_view"></div>
<div contenteditable id="code_view" oninput="move_to_the_other_div(this);" onpaste="move_to_the_other_div(this);"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to grab the data from your `el` using `.innerText` instead

The reason being, when you retrieve the information via `innerHTML` it will pull the HTML information from your input field, however, the HTML that you have written is in plain-text, so there are no HTML elements. Therefore, you have to grab the plain-text and set the `innerHTML` of your target div to the string containing the HTML, instead of the HTML syntax currently in the input field.

**It should also be noted that `innerText` does not work with FireFox**

***For Cross-Browser compatibility I would suggest using `textContent` instead***

---

### *textContent*

```
function move_to_the_other_div(el){
    document.getElementById('html_view').innerHTML = el.textContent;
}
```

---

### *innerText*

```js
function move_to_the_other_div(el){
    document.getElementById('html_view').innerHTML = el.innerText;
}
```

```js
function move_to_the_other_div(el){
 document.getElementById('html_view').innerHTML = el.innerText;
}
```

```css
#html_view{
  width:900px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:320px;
}
#code_view{
  width:900px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:320px;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="html_view"></div>
<div contenteditable id="code_view" oninput="move_to_the_other_div(this);" onpaste="move_to_the_other_div(this);"></div>
```

Comment: innerText is not html standard it only solve your problem in ie but not other browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript

Comment: @DuD. updated the answer for cross-browser compatibility

Comment: `innerText` works fine for me on chrome but i will use `textContent` as you suggested. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Adjit it looks good. May be use this for <ie9 support innerHTML = el.innerText || el.textContent

Comment: Here is a [demonstration of the execution of innerHTML and textContent](http://jsbin.com/seyiqi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I used the jquery $(el).text(). Very easy. Don't know about it's compatibility with standards as mentioned above. Perhaps others can comment on that.