# Onclick unable to find function

Tags: javascript

I was working on a Timer code and its working fine but I'm unable to trigger on button click. I believe there is a silly mistake that I'm not able to figure out and was looking for help.

When I click on button, I get following error in console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startTimer is not defined

I even have tried using `$(document).ready()` and defined functions in it still no luck.

#### Code

```js
function timer(){
    var time = {
        sec:00,
        min:00,
        hr:00
    }
    var max = 59;
    var interval = null;

    function update(str){
        time[str]++;
        time[str] = time[str]%60;
        if(time[str] == 0){
            str == "sec"? update("min"):update("hr");
        }
        print(str);
    }

    function print(str){
        var _time = time[str].toString().length == 1?"0" + time[str]:time[str];
        document.getElementById("lbl"+str).innerText = _time;
    }

    function initInterval(){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            update("sec");
        },1000);
    }
    
    function stopTimer(){
     clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    return {
        'init': initInterval,
        'stop': stopTimer
    }
};
var time = new timer();
function startTimer(){
    time.init();
}

function endTimer(){
    time.stop();
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="lblhr">00</span>
    : <span id="lblmin">00</span>
    : <span id="lblsec">00</span>
</div>

<button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
<button onclick="endTimer()">Stop</button>
```

I'm looking for pure JS solution, and not JQuery(`$(btnId).on("click")`).

Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/2/)

Comment: Also you are defining your functions inside a function, so they can't be found as they are inside the function as a closure.

Comment: how does **`new`** `timer();` play with `return {'init': initInterval, 'stop': stopTimer};`?

Comment: `new timer()` function returns object with mentioned properties. I'm not sure its the best way for function as a class, but works fine. Also issue is that I'm unable to even call startTimer function.

Comment: The problem is your use of [innerText instead of innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript) in the print function

Comment: @James Following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/3/) uses self invoking function instead of button click.

Comment: Yup!  That one will also work if you use innerHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, using innerText won't work in most browsers, use innerHTML.  This should work:

```js
function timer(){
    var time = {
        sec:00,
        min:00,
        hr:00
    }
    var max = 59;
    var interval = null;

    function update(str){
        time[str]++;
        time[str] = time[str]%60;
        if(time[str] == 0){
            str == "sec"? update("min"):update("hr");
        }
        print(str);
    }

    function print(str){
        var _time = time[str].toString().length == 1?"0" + time[str]:time[str];
        document.getElementById("lbl"+str).innerHTML = _time;
    }

    function initInterval(){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            update("sec");
        },1000);
    }
    
    function stopTimer(){
     clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    return {
        'init': initInterval,
        'stop': stopTimer
    }
};
var time = new timer();
function startTimer(){
    time.init();
}

function endTimer(){
    time.stop();
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="lblhr">00</span>
    : <span id="lblmin">00</span>
    : <span id="lblsec">00</span>
</div>

<button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
<button onclick="endTimer()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm still confused a bit. Error meant, it was unable to find reference to function, but changing it to innerHTML solved the problem. Also [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/4/) still shows same error.

Comment: That's a JSFiddle related problem.  I just used your code snippet to diagnose the actual problem.

Comment: Yup. That's the problem. Have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/RWBowQ) and its working properly. Thanks once again. I'll add another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

So, your jsfiddle doesn't work because jsfiddle isn't expecting you to assign the `onclick` event in the HTML section.

You need to migrate that to the javascript section. In the HTML you need to assign an id to each button. Then, in the javascript section, have something like

```
document.getElementById("bStart").onclick = startTimer;
```

I also noticed that you have `startTimer_out()` as a function, but your HTML is trying to call `startTimer()`.

Looks like it may just a jsfiddle thing.