# Changing a value of a html tag

Tags: javascript

I am using inside my page `<span>` tag like this

```
<span class="class_name">1500</span>
```

and I have a javascript code who change "1500" to 15%

my question is how to read the number inside the span and print the new number
I want an example code.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM

Comment: var number = parseInt(document.querySelector(".class_name").innerHTML);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: You say you have code that changes the number, and you're asking us for example code that basically does the same thing?

Comment: my code are 
function numberchange(number) { return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

i want it to read from the span and change the number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between innerText and innerHTML in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<span id="thisspan" class="whateverclass">1500</span>
<div id="thevalueis"></div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("thevalueis").innerHTML=document.getElementById("thisspan").innerHTML;
</script>
```

I hope i got your question right. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try
`var number = parseInt(document.querySelector('span.class_name').innerHTML);`