# How do I return this as string not html element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

How do I return this as string not html element?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "<input type='text'/>";
  var res = str.toString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

[image: This is the return result]

Comment: Using innerText replace innerHTML
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript

Comment: `textContent` *may* be more appropriate - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText

Comment: Are you trying to return `#demo` element `html` as string? `.toString()` call is not necessary.

Comment: If you're working with XHTML, there should be a space between `'text'` and `/>`. If you are working with HTML, no `/` is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: not i need the as it is but in string form.textContent only return text content not html

Answer (score 0):

I had use attribute **.textContent** in **javascript** to resolve problem. Maybe it will be help a lot.

**HTML**

```
<body>
Click button to return a string of input.
<br/>
<button onclick="generate();">Try it</button>
<br/><br/>
<span id="demo"></span>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function generate() {
    var str = "<input type='text'/>";
    var res = str.toString();
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = res;
}
</script>
```

**Link for demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hofvb4ky/1/

**Refer from:**

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp