# GetElementsByClassName('..')[0].value = '' does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble putting/updating the value of an element got by class name.

here is my code:

`index.html`:

```
<dl>
   <dt class="dt-messages-number">total</dt>
   <dd class="dd-messages"></dd>
   ...
</dl>
```

`main.js` :

```
...
var parsedRes = JSON.parse(res);
console.log(res.messages);  //prints undefined
console.log(parsedRes.messages); //prints 23 ,okay
document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages')[0].value = '7';  //not working 
document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages')[0].value = 7;  //not working
document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages')[0].value =parsedRes.messages; //not working
```

last three code lines does not work ,it does not update the value of the description element `dd-messages`. Does any one have idea why is that ?

Comment: Form elements have a value attribute. A `dd` is not a form element, and has no value. You probably want to set the `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: use `innerText` instead `value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`.

`.value` is a method used for inputs, for a text inside `<tags></tags>` use `.innerHTML`

Documentation: [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.innerText` OR `innerHTML` instead

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages')[0].innerText = '7';
```

```html
<dl>
   <dt class="dt-messages-number">total</dt>
   <dd class="dd-messages"></dd>
</dl>
```

for difference between `.value`, `.innetText` and `innerHTML` refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, there is no `value` attribute on such DOM elements.

You can use either `innerHTML` or `innerText`. 
If you know your value is safe and contains safe html, you can use **innerHTML**, 
otherwise you should go with **innerText**.

```
e = <your element by class name>;
e.innerText = e.textContent = "your text"; <-- does not render html--/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages')[0].innerHTML = "Hello world"
// OR you can Also Use
var dd = document.getElementsByClassName('dd-messages');
console.log(dd.ClassName = "Hello World")
```

```html
<dl>
   <dt class="dt-messages-number">total</dt>
   <dd class="dd-messages"></dd>
   ...
</dl>
```