# How to read value of spans

Tags: javascript, html

i wanna read the value of a html span.
how i can do this?

here is the code:

```js
//this works
spanRight= document.getElementsByClassName("spanRight")

//but i cant get the text
spanRight = spanRight.text;
```

```html
<span class="spanRight">1234567890</span>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Use `textContent`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list. Please open your browser console to check for error reports and maybe research the selectors you use to fully understand them, I would also recommend you research the properties you try to access of those elements too...

Comment: textContent returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `innerText`.

```
spanRight = spanRight.innerText;
```

There is also `innerHTML` which can return with HTML tags. [Differences are listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

use `textContent` like this Example:

```js
spanRight= document.getElementsByClassName("spanRight")

//but i cant get the text
text = spanRight[0].textContent

alert(text);
```

```html
<span class="spanRight">1234567890</span>
```

Comment: yeah thanks, now it works. i forgott that it returns an array -.-