# Uncaught Typeerror cannot read property

Tags: php, html

I have been working with on project. It was working at first but now I get a error when I moved it to a server that we have. I have been working with html and php. Here is the error "(index):26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at saveTable ((index):26) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):21)" This is from google chrome. And here is line 26 and 21:

Line 21

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveTable();">Spara</button>
```

Line 26

```
xhttp.open("GET", "backend.php?action=save&Adress=" + document.getElementById("Adress").innerText + "&Fastighet=" + document.getElementById("Fastighet").innerText + "&Kostnadsstalle=" + document.getElementById("kostnadsstalle").innerText + "&Fabrikat=" + document.getElementById("Fabrikat").innerText + "&Typ=" + document.getElementById("Typ").innerText + "&Model=" + document.getElementById("Model").innerText, true);
```

Comment: could you please post all your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between innerText and innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml). This might help. `innertext` is not supported in some browsers like Mozilla. As for Google Chrome, I'm not sure but I advice you check this link.

Comment: Don't think that's the problem. It worked before on google chrome. But when I put it on the server this happend.

Comment: It might be a spelling error. I mean is the id "Adress" or "Address".

Comment: And line 26 is too long. Try to split it into multiple lines.

Comment: No spelling errors it's just Swedish :). Will try to split it

Comment: <th>Adress</th> has no id. Give it an ID of "Adress".

Comment: Give all of them IDs

Comment: Check line 38 that's the IDs

Comment: Think I narrowed one of the errors down to this line

Comment: "&Kostnadsstalle=" +document.getElementById("kostnadsstalle").innerText

Comment: *Check line 38 that's the IDs* You gave them IDs in line 38 and was trying to use their ID in line 26. That's the problem.

Comment: *Check line 38 that's the IDs* You gave them IDs in line 38 and was trying to use their ID in line 26. That's the problem.

Comment: Should I move up line 38 above 26? Then I don't understand how it worked before. I have just added some more table content and moved it over to a server that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Give the table headers an `id` before using it.

Edit: Oh. Well. Just saw it now. I don't think this is the reason at all. The function `loadTableContents()` is called before `saveTable()`. So I think your code is perfectly alright. And since you said it worked before the problem is with your server

Comment: First I was thinking that the server was missing php, and it did. So I fixed that. But that didn't help. After 12 hours of trying to find the solution without progress I had to give it a try here. So can you recommend me where to start?

Comment: The problem might be in the php file. I will add it on my post

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was a misstype that's all. I forgot to use capital letter and now it's fixed