# text length from paragraph using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to count characters from paragraph using JavaScript.
example:

HTML:

```
<p id="text">Example</p>
```

Javascript

```
some code
```

output

```
7.
```

I would like to have same effect like jQuery code:

```
$("#text").text().length;
```

but i need JavaScript some help?

I've already tried

```
var x = document.getElementById("text").length;
```

output: undefined

Comment: You are looking for element.innerText

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get `innerHTML/innerText` of an element before calculating its length like this

```js
var x = document.getElementById("text").innerText.length;
console.log("Length - " + x);
```

```html
<p id="text">Example</p>
```

**P.S**  [Read here for Difference between innerText and innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml)

Comment: You should make the distinction between innerHTML, innerText and textContent. innerHTML will count extra spaces and span tags etc.

Comment: Works for me  now I will be able to resize font size depends from window size  it will be great typography 