# Add HTML element inside JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var $document = $(document);
var selector = '[data-rangeslider]';
var $element = $(selector);
// For ie8 support
var textContent = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
// Example functionality to demonstrate a value feedback
function valueOutput(element) {
    var value = element.value;
    var output = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('output')[0] || element.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
    output[textContent] = value + 'mm';
}
$document.on('input', 'input[type="range"], ' + selector, function(e) {
    valueOutput(e.target);
});
```

in the line `output[textContent] = value + 'mm';` I need the output as `value + '<span class="classname">mm</span>'`
I tried most of the things and did a lot of research but no luck so far.

This might be something very simple but I am too new to JavaScript so couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Mamun this won't work. it gives the whole tag as string and shows as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
output[textContent] = value + 'mm';
```

to:

```
output.innerHTML = value + '<span>mm</span>';
```

Also, you could remove the IE8 fallback, as it will not be necessary. All browsers have support for `innerHTML`.

In your code you are assigning the node text and not the node HTML as you should.

You can read more about the difference between `innerText` and `innerHTML` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml).

Comment: thank you, this helped. I now feel so dumb. i tried adding innerHTML after the value. Thank you so much

Comment: @Lucian great! Glad i could help. Tick it if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this solution?

```
output.innerHTML = `${value} <span class="my-class">mm</span>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var textContent = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
```

`textContent` and `innerText` are both functions for adding text to an element you want to use `innerHTML` to add HTML.

Like this:

```
ouput.innerHTML = ...;
```