# Does 'innerText' prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

If I am going to be displaying user-generated input on my site, is it safe enough to just display it by doing `Element.innerText = "user input"` in javascript, or do I need to additionally filter the input to prevent XSS?

Comment: it's safe, but you should still filter and scrub user input for other reasons.

Comment: @dandavis could you elaborate on "other reasons"?

Comment: a few non-xss areas of concern with user-provided content include excessive length, illegal content, sqli, path traversal, and privacy leaks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does 'innerText' prevent XSS?

Not in all cases! The [following excerpt is from the OWASP Foundation regarding unsafe usages of `innerText`](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#usually-safe-methods):

> One example of an attribute which is thought to be safe is innerText. Some papers or guides advocate its use as an alternative to innerHTML to mitigate against XSS in innerHTML. However, depending on the tag which innerText is applied, code can be executed.

The content provides the following example (which I have modified for clarity)

```js
const tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.innerText = `console.log('Inner Text Used')`;
document.body.appendChild(tag); //executes code
```

---

However, in MOST cases, innerText is the method you would use to prevent XSS, and is also [documented on OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-7-fixing-dom-cross-site-scripting-vulnerabilities):

> ... use innerText/textContent. This will solve the problem, and it is the right way to re-mediate DOM based XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: so, as long as you are not putting user input into a <script>, it is fine?

Comment: if you're injecting raw user input as the whole content of a script tag, you likely have bigger problems...

Comment: @Cee, yes in standard non-executable tags such as divs, spans, buttons, etc, innerText or textContent is what you will want to use and will be safe for those types of tags.