# How can I protect my Azure Function against XSS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions, xss

I have an Azure Function that accepts JSON encoded data and saves it into a database. The content from the database is then used on a web site.

The Azure Function accepts strings, for example; `<script>alert("hi")</script>`.

When eventually shown on the web site this script in some circumstances will be executed.

Whilst I will also be addressing the issues in the web site. Within the Azure Function I want to implement a positive XSS Prevention Model.

For example ASP.NET will validate requests such as form submissions, and emit `HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`.

As far as I know Azure Functions do not have a similiar feature.

It also seems that I can't co-opt the ASP.NET functionaility.

The best option I have found so far is to use [`AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.5.1#System_Web_Security_AntiXss_AntiXssEncoder_HtmlEncode_System_String_System_Boolean_), to encode content and check if the encoded content is different.

Is there another approach I should consider or is this the *solution*?

Comment: Can't you use a library to escape HTML characters?

Comment: @anthonygood that's basically what `AntiXssEncoder` is doing.

Comment: When applying the content to a web page, use `innerText` not `innerHtml` to prevent the content from being treated as HTML.  `innerText` will prevent XSS in *most* cases:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707031/does-innertext-prevent-xss

Comment: See https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#rule-7---fixing-dom-cross-site-scripting-vulnerabilities

Comment: can't you escape everything when you render it on the site?

Comment: @steve sure, I'm doing that also. This is a defense in depth to have multiple layers of protection.

Comment: @JamesWood asp.net will only reject if the query param contains anything suspicious. If the injection comes in in the body it will not complain cuz it will be doing url encode in razor.

Comment: How did you use AntiXssEncoder when it is not available in .Net core

Comment: @RahulShinde if I recall correctly, this was on Azure Functions Version 1 which used .NET Framework.