# How can i change innerHTML +1?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the innerHTML so for every circle thats the same it adds +1

```
if (document.getElementById("circle1").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("circle5").style.backgroundColor) {
    document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML = +1
}

if (document.getElementById("circle2").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("circle6").style.backgroundColor) {
    document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML = +1
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML+ = "+1"`. If you want to append the string.

Comment: Well then it shows me +1 and not 2 how i wanted it to...

Comment: Do you mean like counter?

Comment: so the numbre is 2 when both are the same

Comment: @Dario What do you have here ? `document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML`? and what result do you expect?

Comment: Then why not **read** the current value and add `1` to it?

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt  i want a dot to change the numbre from 0 to 2 when poth circles are the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [**innerText**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) then. First get the old value and cast to Number then add by 1 and replace the old value. Example:

```
if (document.getElementById("circle1").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("circle5").style.backgroundColor) {
    let obj = document.getElementById("point2");
    let oldValue = Number(obj.innerText);
    obj.innerText = oldValue + 1;
}

if (document.getElementById("circle2").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("circle6").style.backgroundColor) {
    let obj = document.getElementById("point2");
    let oldValue = Number(obj.innerText);
    obj.innerText = oldValue + 1;
}
```

See [**difference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml) between `innerText` and `innerHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML` doesn't give you a number, so you cannot add **1** to it. first you need to parse the content to a number (like with **parseInt** or **Number**), and then you can add **1**.

```js
// creating the reference variable (for smaller code)
var point2 = document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML

if (document.getElementById("circle1").style.backgroundColor ==
  document.getElementById("circle5").style.backgroundColor) {
  document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML = increment(point2)
}
if (document.getElementById("circle2").style.backgroundColor ==
  document.getElementById("circle6").style.backgroundColor) {
  document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML = increment(point2)
}

// function to increment the value of point2
function increment(html) {
  return Number(document.getElementById("point2").innerHTML) + 1
}
```

```css
#circle1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#circle5 {
  background-color: red;
}

#circle2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#circle6 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1">C1</div>
<div id="circle5">C5</div>
<br />
<div id="circle2">C2</div>
<div id="circle6">C6</div>

<div id="point2">0</div>
```