# How to fix displaying html symbols

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a quiz and I have problem with displaying HTML symbols.
For example instead of " it shows `&quot;`
Here is whole code: https://codepen.io/mixereq/pen/GVdoWV

```
const result = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
for(let i=0; i<result.results.length; i++) {
    let categoryElement = document.createElement('div');
    let questionElement = document.createElement('div');
    let answersElement = document.createElement('div');

    categoryElement.className = 'category';
    questionElement.className = 'question';
    answersElement.className = 'answers';

    categoryElement.innerText = result.results[i].category;
    questionElement.innerText = result.results[i].question;
    if(result.results[i].correct_answer == 'True') {
        answersElement.innerText = result.results[i].correct_answer + result.results[i].incorrect_answers[0];
    } else {
        answersElement.innerText = result.results[i].incorrect_answers[0] + result.results[i].correct_answer;
    }

    container.appendChild(categoryElement);
    container.appendChild(questionElement);
    container.appendChild(answersElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` to set your content. Then the browser will interpret the value as HTML and not plain text, and will parse and render it, instead of just displaying it verbatim.

Of course when displaying HTML from a 3rd-party API this should be used with caution - be aware of the risk of things like script injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`:

```
const result = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
for(let i=0; i<result.results.length; i++) {
    let categoryElement = document.createElement('div');
    let questionElement = document.createElement('div');
    let answersElement = document.createElement('div');

    categoryElement.className = 'category';
    questionElement.className = 'question';
    answersElement.className = 'answers';

    categoryElement.innerHTML = result.results[i].category;
    questionElement.innerHTML = result.results[i].question;
    if(result.results[i].correct_answer == 'True') {
        answersElement.innerHTML = result.results[i].correct_answer + result.results[i].incorrect_answers[0];
    } else {
        answersElement.innerHTML = result.results[i].incorrect_answers[0] + result.results[i].correct_answer;
    }

    container.appendChild(categoryElement);
    container.appendChild(questionElement);
    container.appendChild(answersElement);
 }
```

More info: [Difference between innerText and innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **innerText** for  **innerHTML** .

**innerText** just put plain text ignoring special characters.

```
categoryElement.innerText = result.results[i].category;
```

for

```
categoryElement.innerHTML = result.results[i].category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer, that you got from backend is wrong - contains unwanted ". Dirty method to fix this, is replacing with regex.

```
questionElement.innerText = result.results[i].question.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```