# unknown error caused every innerHTML to break

Tags: javascript, html

```
button = document.getElementById("button");
//creates "clicker" in js
clicker = document.getElementById("clicker");
//creates "reset" in js
reset = document.getElementById("reset");

//Random Number Chooser
var random;
document.getElementById("ret").innerHTML = "_";

//randomize button
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  document.getElementById("ret").innerHTML = random;
});

//Click Counter
var clickerNum = 0;
document.getElementById("clicky").innerHTML = clickerNum;

//reset button
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clickerNum = 0;
  document.getElementById("clicky").innerHTML = clickerNum;
  document.getElementById("ret").innerHTML = "_";
});

//click button
clicker.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clickerNum++;
  document.getElementById("clicky").innerHTML = clickerNum;
});

//input receive/return
document.getElementById("retAnswer").innerHTML = "You submitted: ";
//submit button function
function submitAnswer() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  document.getElementById("retAnswer").innerHTML = "You submitted: " + answer;
}

//Guess which button
var gameOrder = "";
var playerInput = "";
document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = gameOrder;



//this part
function startGame(){
  gameOrder = "";
  playerInput = "";
  document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = gameOrder;
  memoryGame();
}

function memoryGame(){
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  if(randomNum == 1){
    //make button 1 turn green
    gameOrder += "1";
  }
  else if(randomNum ==2){
    //make button 2 turn green
    gameOrder += "2";
  }
  else{
    //make button 3 turn green
    gameOrder += "3";
  }

  document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = gameOrder;
}

function addInput(var input){
  playerInput += input;
}
```

I am learning web development and I am trying to add a little memorization game to my website. The problem is that when I added the last part (commented "this part") all the innerHTML parts broke. Every one on the page so it doesn't even have a space for it. I was wondering if maybe it is because there may be a limit to how many innerHTML you can use? I don't really think that's it, but I can't find any error that would cause all the innerHTML to break. I commented out the last part and everything worked again, so I know that the problem is in the last section.

````
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    Random Number Chooser
  </header>
  <br>
  <!--- Random Number Chooser --->
  <div class="wrapper" id="button">
    <button type="button">Randomize!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="ret">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <header>
    Click Counter
  </header>
  <!--- Click Counter --->
  <div class="wrapper" id="reset">
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="clicky">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="clicker">
    <button type="button">Click</button>
  </div>
  <!--- input receive and return --->
  <br>
  <header>
    Input Receive/Return
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="input1" />
    <button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="retAnswer">
  </div>
  <br>
  <!--- Which button --->
  <header>
    Guess which button
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper" id="restart">
    <button onclick="startGame()">Start/Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="order">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="wrapper" id="but1">
    <button onclick="addInput("1")">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="but2">
    <button onclick="addInput("2")">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" id="but3">
    <button onclick="addInput("3")">3</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="wrapper" id="gameSubmit">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: what is the actual error? What is the HTML so it can be run?

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: Your problem may be due to your understanding of innerHTML....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml

Comment: I see one syntax error at `function addInput(var input){` remove the `var`

Comment: michael that was it, thank you

Comment: You also have syntax errors in your HTML: `<button onclick="addInput("1")">1</button>` should be `<button onclick="addInput('1')">1</button>` likewise for 2 and 3

Comment: and add `type="button"` to your buttons so they are not submit buttons.

Comment: Get something like eslint or jslint to help find the issues in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the last function of your code, noticed how instead of saying `function addInput(input)` you said `function addInput(var input)`

You can't declare variables there, the section between parentheses is used to pass parameters. This broke the script. So if you just remove `var` from the function it will work.

Here's the function should look like

```
function addInput(input){
    playerInput += input;
}
```

Good luck with your learning!