# Use innerText to retrieve text from hidden HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the text from an html element which is hidden with css. I know that per the specs innerText will abide the css rules. But the alternative of using textContent ignores line break and tabs which I need to keep in the string.

Is there any way around this?

For simplicity please see the following example:

```js
const inntxt = document.querySelector('.expandable').innerText
console.log(inntxt) // Here we don't get the hidden div's text.

const txtct = document.querySelector('.expandable').textContent

console.log(txtct) // Here the result removes the line break.
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='expandable'>
  <span class='visib'>
    Red balloon
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class='hidden'>
    Yellow badge<br>Green ribbon
  </span>
</div>
```

I guess one way around it would be to replace the `<br>` with my own char like # by appending it instead of the `<br>`, but there must be a better way no?

**UPDATE**

To be more clear the end result should be:

For example if you would console.log() the string in node, then the string from our innerText or textContent should be:
'Red balloon\nYellow Badge\nGreen ribbon'

Comment: In short what is the end result what you want to get?

Comment: What about using `.innerHTML`? You could do that and replace the `<br>` with a `\n`

Comment: @GMaiolo Can you please supply an example

Comment: @S.Schenk added an answer with a snippet, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

It is very unintuitive that [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) doesn't retrieve `<br>` new lines.

I suggest using a dummy element in Javascript using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and replacing all `<br>` with `\n<br>`.

Take a look at this code, I think it solves your issue:

```js
const expandable = document.querySelector('.expandable')
const auxEl = document.createElement('div')
auxEl.innerHTML = expandable.innerHTML.replace(/(\<br\>)/, '\n$1')
const textContent = auxEl.textContent

console.log({ textContent })

/* Yields
{
  "textContent": "\n  \n    Red balloon\n  \n  \n    Yellow badge\nGreen ribbon\n  \n"
}
*/
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='expandable'>
  <div class='visib'>
    Red balloon
  </div>
  <div class='hidden'>
    Yellow badge<br>Green ribbon
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use the following script to get innerText

```js
const inntxt = document.getElementsByClassName('expandable')[0].innerText;
console.log(inntxt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about what you're trying to achieve here, but what you might want to do is change `innerText` to `innerHTML` and then the line breaks are preserved.

> Unlike `innerText`, though, `innerHTML` lets you work with HTML rich
>   text and doesn't automatically encode and decode text. In other words,
>   `innerText` retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text,
>   whereas `innerHTML` retrieves and sets the content in HTML format.

Quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19030857/4073621.

Comment: And how would I remove all the html markings the string (like div, span etc)?

Comment: This is what happens with `innerHTML`. It's either plain text or HTML that you can grab from an element.