# Why Are My Variables Coming Back As Undefined From an External Javascript Page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Why Are My Variables Coming Back Us Undefined From External Javascript Page?

So basically, I am sending variables to javascript from a php page.
On page 1, the users fills out a form.

The data is then passed to page 2, where the data is taken from the post and is put into php variables then echoed onto the page.

```
    $name = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
    $company = isset($_POST['company']) ? $_POST['company'] : "";
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : "";
    $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : "";
    $state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : "";
    $country = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : "";
    <p id="Name"><?php echo $name ?></p>
    <p id="Email"><?php echo $email ?></p>
    <p id="Company"><?php echo $company ?></p>
    <p id="Phone"><?php echo $phone ?></p>
    <p id="City"><?php echo $city ?></p>
    <p id="State"><?php echo $state ?></p>
    <p id="Country"><?php echo $country ?></p>
<center>
<input class="LeonardButton" type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
</center>
```

After this, the user hits a button to send this data along with the data they fill out on page 2, to an javascript page for processing.

The javascript page attempts to take the variables by id and then alert them back to the user on the first page for testing purposes.

```
const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

const focusAndSelect = selector => {
    const elem = $(selector);
    elem.focus();
    elem.select();  
};

const processEntries = () => 
{
    let name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    let company = document.getElementById("Company").value;
    let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
    let city = document.getElementById("City").value;
    let state = document.getElementById("State").value;
    let country = document.getElementById("Country").value;
    
    alert("Test Alert");
    alert(name);
    alert(email);
    alert(company);
    alert(phone);
    alert(city);
    alert(state);
    alert(country); 
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    $("#calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
});
```

When I click the calculate button and run the javascript, it alerts me back, "test alert", then, "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined".

[image]
I know that the php variables were set and defined on this page because I have them physically show up on top.
[image]

Edit #1: I attempted to use Dzejkob's solution, but the variables are still coming in as undefined. Here is the code I modified and the results in a screenshot.

So I attempted the following code:

```
   let name = document.getElementById("Name").innerText;
    let email = document.getElementById("Email").innerText;
    let company = document.getElementById("Company").innerText;
    let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").innerText;
    let city = document.getElementById("City").innerText;
    let state = document.getElementById("State").innerText;
    let country = document.getElementById("Country").innerText;
```

and

```
    let name = document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML;
let email = document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML;
let company = document.getElementById("Company").innerHTML;
let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").innerHTML;
let city = document.getElementById("City").innerHTML;
let state = document.getElementById("State").innerHTML;
let country = document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML;
```

But the result is the same:

[image: Variables Are Undefined In Alerts Still]

Edit #2: The answer suggested by Dzejkob worked. Apparently, I was pulling the wrong file in the cache. Ivar recommended that I check in the console and I did and then I saw that it was giving me old code.

Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Its just a typo, paragraphs don't have values, so use `innerText` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between innerText, innerHTML, and childNodes\[\].value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-innerhtml-and-childnodes-value)

Comment: @Ivar nope, I ran the test with both .innerText and with ,InnerHTML and they are both coming back as undefined.

Comment: @LeonardTreman [They shouldn't](https://jsfiddle.net/rky72fdc/). Caching maybe?

Comment: @Ivar I thought the same thing, so I completely turned caching off for the staging site, I did one last server cache wipe, then I went incognito on google chrome and disabled the browser cache and had received these results.

Comment: @LeonardTreman Can you inspect the source in your browser and see if it indeed uses `.innerText`/`.innerHTML`? Maybe you are not changing the source you think you change? Like the good old "Making a change in the development environment, but refreshing production environment expecting to see the change" we all run in to from time to time?

Comment: @Ivar I just tested the source and you were right. It was pulling old source code. Once I refreshed it it pulled the correct code successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML or .innerText instead of .value which is property of text field not paragraphs.

Comment: I attempted both sets of these and both came back as undefined.                              let name = document.getElementById("Name").innerText;
 let email = document.getElementById("Email").innerText;
 let company = document.getElementById("Company").innerText;
 let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").innerText;
 let city = document.getElementById("City").innerText;
 let state = document.getElementById("State").innerText;
 let country = document.getElementById("Country").innerText;

Comment: Thats weird. Maybe you got more elements with the same id somewhere. Better to use console.log() and try to console.log(document.getElementById("Country")) whole element - than in console (ctrl+shift+i) at "console" tab you may see which element was found.

Comment: I just tried the console and it's coming back error free in google chrome. I don't use these same elements anywhere. I will try using that console.log now