# can't pass parameters using mouseover listener and can't set top value of element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have been trying to add a mouseover listener in javascript as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class" + i.toString());
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        elements[j].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
            showDiv(i, e.pageX, e.pageY);
        });
    }
}
```

and showDiv is:

```
function showTranslationDiv(idx, x, y){
    const notification = document.getElementsById('div0');
    notification.innerHTML = "You are at: " + x.toString() + " " + y.toString();
    notification.style.top = y.toString() + 'px';
    notification.style.left = x.toString() + 'px';

    notification.style.display = 'flex';
    setTimeout(function () {

        notification.style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
}
```

classes is a list of 3 different class names (the real name is not relevant).

I encountered two problems here:

1. When I use `style.top`, as you see above, it doesn't work and `div0` didn't appear, but if I write a hard-coded top value (`style.top = '400px'` for example) it's working fine.
2. the value of **idx** is always 3 for any class, it should be different for different class indices.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show the HTML

Comment: Your issue with idx always being 3 is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

Your notification isn't appearing because it looks like you have a typo when calling [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

> This:
>
> ```
> const notification = document.getElementsById('div0');
> ```
>
> Should be:
>
> ```
> const notification = document.getElementById('div0');
> ```

---

Your `idx` is always `3` becuase, as @phuzi mentioned in the comments, your event handler forms a closure around the value of `i`. [The linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/14956277) has more information.

> When this:
>
> ```
> showDiv(i, e.pageX, e.pageY);
> ```
>
> Accesses `i` from here:
>
> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
> ```
>
> It always refers to the same instance of `i` that was declared as a `var`.

---

To solve these problems, correct the typo and scope `i` so that its unique to each iteration of the loop creating your event handlers.

```
for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class" + i.toString());
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        elements[j].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
            showDiv(i, e.pageX, e.pageY);
        });
    }
}
```

```
function showTranslationDiv(idx, x, y){
    const notification = document.getElementById('div0');
    notification.innerHTML = "You are at: " + x.toString() + " " + y.toString();
    notification.style.top = y.toString() + 'px';
    notification.style.left = x.toString() + 'px';

    notification.style.display = 'flex';
    setTimeout(function () {

        notification.style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
}
```

---

As a side note, you may want to [use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-innerhtml-and-value) since you're only setting text value. `innerHTML` is a potential [vector for cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). Even though you're likely safe here, it's good practice to avoid it when possible.

```
notification.innerText = `You are at: ${x} ${y}`;
```

Also, you may want to prefer `querySelectorAll` over `getElementsByClassName` because [the latter is rechecked every time you interact with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.class${i}`);
```

Comment: Thanks! it's work now. And thanks for the other tips. Do you have any idea what is the solution for the style.top that didn't work?

Comment: Was the `getElementById` typo not the issue? You're using [`style.top`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_top.asp) correctly. What are the values of `x` and `y` when it fails?

Comment: it wasn't the issue. the value was correct according to mouse position but the assignment wasn't work