# Populating a span with a string including a linked email

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to have have this span have the text below with the email being an active link. But it just prints the entire text as a string including the HTML mark-up.  Do I need to escape it some other way?

ASPX file:

```
  <span id ="Email" runat="server"></span>
```

Code Behind:

```
  Email.InnerText =  "Email responses here:<a href='mailto:this@that.com'>this@that.com</a>";
```

Comment: Instead of `innerText` use `innerHtml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between innerText, innerHTML and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-innerhtml-and-value)

Comment: That seems to be it.