# Why can't I get the context in this textarea by Playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I have tried some functions in playwright js, such as innerText, textContent.

What I got is the plain text instead of the text in the text area.

I tried to find these innertext in browser inspect, and I cannot find any...

The following is the js code and the screenshot of my problem.

[The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKRkR.png)

[What I got in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Dts.png)

```
    console.log(await page.locator("(//div[@class='p-card p-component'])[1]").innerText())
```

Can anyone provide me with some inspirations? I've nearly found every ways but none of them can solve my problem.

Comment: *innerText* isn't a function, it's a property. Anyway, likely you need the value property as *textArea* elements don't have either *innerText* or *textContent* (which are more or less the same thing). [*This answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032002/257182) might help to clear things up.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for your reply! I am still a novice in JS. Then how do I see these text, now that they are neither innerText or textContent.

Comment: `.inputValue()` https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-input-value

Comment: I was commenting on the *innerText* and *textContent* properties of HTML elements. In Playwright, the *locator* object returned by *page.locator* has methods that return the value of similarly named DOM properties, so *locator(…).textContent()* returns the matched element's textContent. As @candre says, you can get the value of input, textArea and select elements with the *inputValue* method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try inputValue() method.

```
console.log(await page.locator("(//div[@class='p-card p-component'])[1]").innerText())
```