# How to insert HTML div tags into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, button, tags

Please help me add the html div tag in the script

```
const button = this.createElement("div");

button.classList.add("start_button");
let border = 0;
if (typeof this.config.backgroundImg === "string") {
  button.classList.add("button");
  border = 1;
}
button.innerText = (typeof this.config.startBtnName === 'string') 
                 ? this.config.startBtnName 
                 : this.local("test");
```

`this.config.startBtnName` is a text, i need this text to be inside `<div>`

I tried this `'<div>'+this.config.startBtnName+'</div>'`, but then the div is output as plain text, not an html tag.

Comment: use innerHTML not innerText.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between innerText, innerHTML and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-innerhtml-and-value)

Comment: Should `button` be an actual button? If so, you should use `<button>` instead of `<div>`. Further, does `this.config.startBtnName` have to be _specifically_ inside a `<div>`? [Cat mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77857103/13561410#comment137257402_77857132) that a `<div>` inside a `<button>` is technically not permitted; perhaps you may want to use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`?

Answer (score 2):

To insert HTML content, including a `div` tag, into a JavaScript-created element, you should use the `innerHTML` property instead of `innerText`. The `innerText` property treats the assigned value as plain text and does not parse it as HTML. However, `innerHTML` will treat the assigned value as HTML, allowing you to insert tags like `div`.

Here's how you can modify your code to include the `div` tag:

```js
const button = this.createElement("div");
button.classList.add("start_button");
let border = 0;

if (typeof this.config.backgroundImg === "string"){
    button.classList.add("button");
    border = 1;
}

// Using innerHTML to insert div tag
button.innerHTML = (typeof this.config.startBtnName === 'string') 
    ? '<div>' + this.config.startBtnName + '</div>' 
    : '<div>' + this.local("test") + '</div>';
```

In this code, `innerHTML` is used to set the content of the button. If `this.config.startBtnName` is a string, it wraps that string in a `div` tag. Otherwise, it falls back to using the result of `this.local("test")`, also wrapped in a `div` tag.

Please ensure that `this.config.startBtnName` and the return value of `this.local("test")` are properly sanitized if they can include user input, to avoid potential security risks such as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

Comment: Good answer but also note that including a div element inside a button element may not be the best idea. My reasoning for this is according to MDN 1) the only permitted content for the <button> element is non-interactive *phrasing* content (see the Technical Summary section at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#technical_summary), and 2) the <div> element does not belong to the *phrasing* content category (see the Phrasing section at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content)

Comment: Considering what @Cat wrote: A generic (and here permitted!) `<span>` instead of a generic `<div>` element` seems more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, I agree too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.createElement` to make a div element, then add the text to it.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div'); // consider using span instead
div.append(typeof this.config.startBtnName === 'string' ? this.config.startBtnName : this.local("test"));
button.replaceChildren(div);
```